# Creating a zip file on a disk with not enough space

Tags: c#, zip, diskspace

If you try to create a zip on a  disk with not enough space available.
The method `system.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()` will throw an exception and will let a zip file containing truncated files.

Because the file is useless and take all the remaining memory, I would like to remove the zip file and here is what I have so far :

```
      try
        {
            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(tempPath, pathToExport);
        }
      catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(pathToExport))
            {
                File.Delete(pathToExport);
            }
        }
```

This do not work because the file is still used by the process.

Any sugestion on how to release the file ?

Comment: Don't you need to close the file before trying to delete it?

Comment: @Zerte, ??? `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` doesn't return a stream or similar that would need to be disposed/closed...

Comment: Is the code in your question the actual real code reproducing the problem, or is it simplifed with your real code looking differently?

Comment: The FileSystem may be a little laggy. Does it work if you add a little pause? Like `Sleep(100);` or respective `await Task.Delay(100)` ?

Comment: It doesn't work with a little pause

Comment: And yes this is a simplifed version of the code

Comment: If the code in your question is simplified, then please look in your real code whether and where your code might try to open the file before you attempt to delete it. If there are such instances, make sure you are using `using` constructs to avoid having dangling file handles (which would keep the file open and locked up until a future run of the GC collects the associated file stream object, thus preventing it from being deleted)

Comment: Well that's what I checked before asking the question, and if  i didn't post all the code, it's because the same error can be reproduce with this one.

Comment: @NicolasGrimault, i cannot reproduce your problem here (i used a 1GB RAM disk, with my project targeting .NET 4.6.1). I suggest you create a small test project just with the code in your question and nothing else and try to reproduce your problem this way. Will it still happen when only using the simple code in your question? If it is not happening with the simple code in your question, you will have to take another look into your real code. If the problem occurs even with your simple code from the question, there might be some other software/service on your system that might be interfering...

Comment: Yes I have already create a small project in .net 4.5.2 and I always reproduced this problem. Maybe i wasn't clear but its memory on hard disk that is missing (not RAM). exemple trying to create a 20 mo zip file on a disk with 10 mo available

Comment: I don't think there is a another  software using the file, when triyng to delete manually, it's say that the file is used by VS

Comment: Well, you will have to troubleshoot the problem by yourself, i am afraid. (By the way, from an applications perspective, it should be irrelevant whether a drive/volume is on a HDD, SSD, or RAM disk)

Comment: ok, Thanks for your help

Comment: Hmm, one more thing, perhaps. What if you run your small test project as Release build outside of VS? Does the problem then still occur? (Not that it is some weird side-effect/bug of VS, its debugger or of one of the VS add-ons you might perhaps have installed)

Comment: Well, it works fine with dotnet run

Comment: This indicates that probably something is up with your VS installation. Unfortunately, i have not really a clue what it could be :-(